# Asp-fallback-href always triggers

Tags: css, asp.net

I play with asp core and want a fallback to my local bootswatchSlate.css which is in the wwwroot folder only if I can't access bootstrap from a cdn:

Layout.cshtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="css/bootswatchSlate.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="hidden"
          asp-fallback-test-property="visibility"
          asp-fallback-test-value="hidden"/>
```

I always get the bootswatchSlate.css although the cdn is live and I can reach it. Where is my problem?

Answer (score 7):

The fallback is always being loaded because your test indicates that the `css` file was not loaded. I looked at the css and the `.hidden` class has the  style `display:none`. I have found choosing the fallback test takes a little trial an error because many of the styles in the css file are transformed by the browser such as `em` values.

You should update your html to match the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      asp-fallback-href="css/bootswatchSlate.css"
      asp-fallback-test-class="hidden"
      asp-fallback-test-property="display"
      asp-fallback-test-value="none" />
```